# Create dataframe with values, but changing column and row names

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I want to create a data frame with 284 rows and 284 columns. I have another data frame of rap music that has the columns 'song_title' with the song title names and another column 'lyrics' that has the lyrics to each song. I want to fill my new data frame with the lyrics as both rows and columns, but I want the title of the columns and rows to  be the song_titles, but the 'value' to be the lyrics. I am not sure how to do this (I am new to R), any help would be appreciated. Below is the code I have so far.

```
df = data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=284, nrow=284))
colnames(df) = drake_lyrics$song_title
row.names(df) = drake_lyrics$song_title

Output:

                 Best I Ever Had      Forever    Marvin's Room
Best I Ever Had      NA                 NA           NA
Forever              NA                 NA           NA
Marvin's Room        NA                 NA           NA


What I want to achieve is the following:

                 Best I Ever Had      Forever              Marvin's Room
Best I Ever Had      "im just.."       "my name is"           "hell yeah.."
Forever            "im just..       "my name is"            "hell yeah.."
Marvin's Room       "im just.."      "my name is"         "hell yeah.."
```

Comment: Difficult to understand what you want. Why would the song names be in both rows and columns? What is the value of an element that intersects two different songs? Renaming rows and columns is easy, but I don't think that is your problem here. You will need to add some test data to get a proper answer.

Comment: The aim is to run a jaccard similarity function. I will add some test data

Comment: Without knowing what `drake_lyrics` contains, the desired output is still not 100% clear. But I would suggest that the result matrix should ideally be the output of your similarity algorithm. You might not need to create the `NA` table at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you'd like to achieve?

```
#Dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(songs = c("Hello", "World", "Some", "Nice"), 
                 lyrics = c("abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1

#   songs lyrics
# 1 Hello   abcd
# 2 World   efgh
# 3  Some   ijkl
# 4  Nice   mnop

#Create a matrix (`simplify = "matrix"`)
#wherein each row is the vector
#df1$lyrics
#And the number of rows is 
#the same as the number of rows in df1
#The output is then transposed
df2 <- t(replicate(nrow(df1), df1$lyrics, simplify = "matrix"))

#Then the row names and column names
#are set to the names of the corresponding songs
colnames(df2) <- df$songs
rownames(df2) <- colnames(df2)

df2

#       Hello  World  Some   Nice  
# Hello "abcd" "efgh" "ijkl" "mnop"
# World "abcd" "efgh" "ijkl" "mnop"
# Some  "abcd" "efgh" "ijkl" "mnop"
# Nice  "abcd" "efgh" "ijkl" "mnop"
```

Comment: The output given here is not the result of Jaccard similarity. I think I misunderstand the question.

Comment: @randr I think what the OP wants is to pass this matrix as an **input** to a Jaccard similarity function.

Comment: Yes - which is why I find it odd to have all of the values for one column being the same. The **input** should surely be two vectors (or in this case one vector compared against itself) and the **output** a matrix of pairwise relationships.

Comment: @randr that's what I thought too, but then again, who am I to question the OP?